# e.nodename undefined when using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering

I wrote this nice bit of code to use for input boxes at the top of various tables using a `class='filt'` to allow the table to be filtered based on those inputs. Of course, most of the inputs are more than 1 letter so I wanted to add a timer or similar debouncing function. the below works fine, but when I added the timer, I started getting a

> "e.nodename is undefined"

error. any ideas?

```
<script>
    var typingTimer;
    var doneTypingInterval = 1000;
    $('.filt').on('keyup', function () {
        var children = $(this).parent().parent().find("input");
        clearTimeout(typingTimer);
        typingTimer = setTimeout(function () {
            $("#table1 tbody tr").show();
            for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                var tableChild = children[i];
                if (tableChild.value) {
                    var valarr = tableChild.value.split(",,");  //multiple filter separator 
                    for (var az = 0; az < valarr.length; az++) {
                        if (valarr[az].charAt(0) == '~') {   //negation operator
                            var val2 = valarr[az].substr(1);
                            $("#table1 tbody tr:not(:not(:has(td:eq(" + tableChild.id + "):contains('" + val2 + "'),td:eq(" + tableChild.id + ") [value*='" + val2 + "'])))").hide();
                        } else {                              //standard filter
                            $("#table1 tbody tr:not(:has(td:eq(" + tableChild.id + "):contains('" + valarr[az] + "'),td:eq(" + tableChild.id + ") [value*='" + valarr[az] + "']))").hide();
                        }
                    }
                    $("#table1 tbody tr").eq(0).show();
                }
            }
            $(this).focus();  //annoying extra code for MS browsers
            var thistext = $(this).val();
            $(this).val('').val(thistext);
        }, doneTypingInterval);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Nobody wants to search through all that messy code. Please trim it down, or atleast tell us the line number the error is on.

Comment: i think i figured out the issue. it's the annoying MS browser code at the end. it references $(this), but i'm not sure how to work around that.

Answer (score 1):

Just get the `this` into another parameter before you start the timer as shown below. Because `setTimeout` has it's own scope.

```
<script>
        var typingTimer;
        var doneTypingInterval = 1000;
        $('.filt').on('keyup', function () {
            var children = $(this).parent().parent().find("input");
            clearTimeout(typingTimer);

            //Get this into self
            var self =  this;

            typingTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                $("#table1 tbody tr").show();
                for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                    var tableChild = children[i];
                    if (tableChild.value) {
                        var valarr = tableChild.value.split(",,");  //multiple filter separator 
                        for (var az = 0; az < valarr.length; az++) {
                            if (valarr[az].charAt(0) == '~') {   //negation operator
                                var val2 = valarr[az].substr(1);
                                $("#table1 tbody tr:not(:not(:has(td:eq(" + tableChild.id + "):contains('" + val2 + "'),td:eq(" + tableChild.id + ") [value*='" + val2 + "'])))").hide();
                            } else {                              //standard filter
                                $("#table1 tbody tr:not(:has(td:eq(" + tableChild.id + "):contains('" + valarr[az] + "'),td:eq(" + tableChild.id + ") [value*='" + valarr[az] + "']))").hide();
                            }
                        }
                        $("#table1 tbody tr").eq(0).show();
                    }
                }
                $(self).focus();  //annoying extra code for MS browsers
                var thistext = $(self).val();
                $(self).val('').val(thistext);
            }, doneTypingInterval);
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a contextual issue. You're referencing `this`, thinking it points to the `.filt` element, but you don't realise that a timeout callback changes the context to `window`.

```
$('.foo').on('click', function() {
    this; //is the clicked element
    setTimeout(function() {
        this; //is window
    }, 1);
});
```

There's a few ways to reference a different `this`. jQuery's `.bind()` allows you to contextualise the callbcak with any `this` you like, i.e. the element.

```
$('.foo').on('click', function() {
    this; //is the clicked element
    setTimeout(function() {
        this; //is also element
    }.bind(this), 1); //<-- note bind()
});
```

Alternatively, you can also pass the outer this as a function argument to the timeout callback, via an immediately-executed function:

```
$('.foo').on('click', function() {
    this; //is the clicked element
    setTimeout((function(outer_this) { return function() {
        outer_this; //is also element
    }; })(this), 1);
});
```

Or simply make a variable referencing it before entering the timeout:

```
$('.foo').on('click', function() {
    var outer_this = this; //<-- cache outer scope
    this; //is the clicked element
    setTimeout(function() {
        outer_this; //is also element
    }, 1);
});
```